# how to filter new clients in mdx based on a date-attribute?

Tags: attributes, filtering, mdx

I am fairly new to MDX and I want to filter all of the new clients from the Client-dimension showing the number of their transactions. I use the code below. Syntactically OK but **not** returning the 1931 clients I am searching for but It returns an empty set.

```
select 
    {[Measures].[Transaction Count]} on columns
,   filter([Client].[Client ID],[Client].[Date Birth] >= '2016-01-01') on rows 
from [Transactions];
```

Your second query is the following:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Transaction Count] } ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { ([Client].[Client ID].[Client ID].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
    DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
       MEMBER_CAPTION
     , MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
 FROM ( 
    SELECT 
     ( Filter( 
         [Client].[Date Birth].[Date Birth].ALLMEMBERS
       , Instr( [Client].[Date Birth].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), '2016' ) = 1 ) ) ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [DW3_Summary]
 ) 
  CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem `[Client].[Date Birth] >= '2016-01-01'` as you have a member type on the left of the operator `>=` and a date type on the right side.

I think you could create a measure that is the value of the Date Birth hierarchy, then try filtering on that:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[DateBirthValue] AS
  [Client].[Date Birth].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE
SELECT 
    [Measures].[Transaction Count] ON 0
,   FILTER(
       [Client].[Client ID].MEMBERS
      ,[Measures].[DateBirthValue] >= '2016-01-01'
    ) ON 1
FROM [Transactions];
```

Unfortunately I do not have access to the AdvWrks cube to test the above, so fingers crossed!

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY [Measures].[Transaction Count] ON 0
, NON EMPTY [Client].[Client ID].[Client ID].ALLMEMBERS 
    ON ROWS 
 FROM 
   ( 
    SELECT 
         [Client].[Date Birth].[Date Birth].&[2016-01-01] 
        :
         NULL 
       ON 0 
    FROM [DW3_Summary]
   );
```

Comment: thanks whytheq. But it feels a little awkward to transpose a dim-value to a measure. Or am I missing your solution?
When I query in SSRS-MDX-Designer then I get this query.
'SELECT 
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Transaction Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ([Client].[Client ID].[Client ID].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( Filter( [Client].[Date Birth].[Date Birth].ALLMEMBERS, Instr( [Client].[Date Birth].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), '2016' )  = 1  ) ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM [DW3_Summary]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE'

Comment: thanks whytheq. But it feels a little awkward to transpose a dim-value to a measure. Or am I missing your solution?
When I query in SSRS-MDX-Designer then I get this query.
`SELECT 
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Transaction Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ([Client].[Client ID].[Client ID].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( Filter( [Client].[Date Birth].[Date Birth].ALLMEMBERS, Instr( [Client].[Date Birth].currentmember.Properties( 'Member_Caption' ), '2016' )  = 1  ) ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM [DW3_Summary]) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE`

Comment: "feels a little awkward"... it's actually not so strange i.e using the member value or member caption in a measure is a pretty standard strategy to use in mdx. Your subselect is ok but you could simplicfy the script quite an just paste it into ssrs's mdx window - let me add a slightly similar version using the range operator into my answer.